# Volley incorrect post response after first call

Tags: php, android, android-volley, offlineapps

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to implement a simple offline feature in my app, which takes leaves from employees when device is offline and update that leave data to server when device is online for which I am doing following steps

- Storing the data in local database if device offline
- checking connectivity change via the broadcast receiver
- and when device online make a network call to post the data to web server

All this is working fine and the data is also getting posted on web server properly but the problem is that it is only getting posted for the first time after that it doesn't work

**What I know so far about the issue**

Every time I make a clean install it works perfectly but when I again try to make another network call to post data then it doesn't work instead volley shows an incorrect response code which is success but the at the backend no data were posted at all

I had echo 1 for success and 0 for failure in php backend but don't know why volley return 1 every time even if data is not posted

**leaveFragment**

```
        if (isNetworkAvailable(getContext())) {
        BackgroundWorkerLeave backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorkerLeave(getContext());
        backgroundWorker.execute("leave", from_date, to_date, day_count, leave_type, reason, emp_id);
    } else {
        // save data offline
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        db.insertItem(from_date, to_date, day_count, leave_type, reason);
    }
```

NetworkChangeRecevier //broadcast receiver for network change monitoring

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("MyReceiver","Received intent..");
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getDetailedState() == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
            DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
           int count = db.getofflineCount();
            // Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //
             if (count > 0) {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Internet connected updating data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               OfflineWorkerLeave offlineWorkerLeave = new OfflineWorkerLeave(context, db.getAllOfflineLeave());
               offlineWorkerLeave.updateLeave();
           }else {
               Toast.makeText(context, "All updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        } else if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getDetailedState() == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Offline mode activated..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**DatabaseHelper.class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "employee_leave";
private static final String COL_ID = "col_id";
private static final String COL_DAYCOUNT = "daycount";
private static final String COL_FROM = "from_date";
private static final String COL_TO = "to_date";
private static final String COL_TYPE = "type";
private static final String COL_REASON = "reason";
Context context;
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leave(date_applied varchar, date_leave varchar, status varchar);");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_FROM +
            " TEXT," + COL_TO + " TEXT," + COL_DAYCOUNT +
            " TEXT," + COL_TYPE + " TEXT," +
            COL_REASON + " TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

//this method will add users in the database
public void insertItem(String from, String to, String status) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO leave VALUES ('" + from + "','" + to + "','" + status + "');");
    db.close();
}

public void insertItem(String from, String to, String day_count, String leave_type, String reason) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (from_date,to_date,daycount,type,reason)" +
            " VALUES ('" + from + "','" + to + "','" + day_count + "','" +
            leave_type + "','" + reason + "');");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Leave stored on the device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
}

public int getofflineCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return c.getCount();
}

public Map<String, String> getAllOfflineLeave() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SharedPreferences sp_login = context.getSharedPreferences("login_status", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor login_editor = sp_login.edit();
    String emp_id = sp_login.getString("userid", "null");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COL_ID + " DESC LIMIT 1", null);
       if (c.moveToFirst()) {
           params.put("from_date", c.getString(1));
           params.put("to_date", c.getString(2));
           params.put("day_count", c.getString(3));
           params.put("leave_type", c.getString(4));
           params.put("reason", c.getString(5));
           params.put("emp_id", emp_id);
       }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return params;
}

public List<Model> getAllLeave() {
    List<Model> leaveList = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from leave", null);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        Model logs = new Model();
        String status = "";
        logs.setFdate(c.getString(0));
        logs.setTdate(c.getString(1));
        if (c.getString(2).equals("0")) {
            status = "Rejected";
        } else if (c.getString(2).equals("2")) {
            status = "Approved";
        } else {
            status = "Pending";
        }
        logs.setLeaveReason(status);
        leaveList.add(logs);
    }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return leaveList;
}

public void deleteRecord() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE from leave");
    db.close();
}

public void deleteOfflineRecord() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE from " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
}
```

}

**offlineWorkerleave.class**

```
public class OfflineWorkerLeave {
Context context;
DatabaseHelper db;
Map<String, String> params;

public OfflineWorkerLeave(Context context, Map<String, String> params) {
    this.context = context;
    this.params = params;
    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public void updateLeave() {
    String url = "exapmle.com/applyleave.php";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                     if (response.contains("1\t")){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully data updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         db.deleteOfflineRecord();
                    } else if (response.contains("0\t")){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

}

**applyLeave.php**

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$ldate = $_POST['from_date'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$leavetype = $_POST['leave_type'];
$to_date = $_POST['to_date'];
$daycount = $_POST['day_count'];
$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
$todaydate = date('d-m-Y');

if(strtotime($ldate) > strtotime($to_date))
{
    echo "Please Select appropriate Dates";
}
else
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO empleave (empid, leave_date, leave_todate, daycount, reason, leavetype, createdDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param ( "issssss", $emp_id, $ldate, $to_date, $daycount, $reason, $leavetype, $date);
    if($stmt->execute ())
    {
        echo "1";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "0";
    }
}

?>
```

I don't understand this problem the only thing I can do is to have make this work is I found was to clear application data manually and start again because app works only first time and then after incorrect success response from volley.

Still trying to make it work and let me know you if anybody wants to know more about it.

Comment: print params content in OfflineWorkerLeave constructor to ensure the data is not empty every time you upload it. And you should close db in `getofflineCount ()` method.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: sorry, it's a wrong operation and now I have correctly edited.

Comment: @vesper thanks, I will make changes and test if it works

Comment: @vesper it's not working, I debugged the code and the params are not empty and volley also had a success response but the data is not updated at backend   Note: But it only works for the first time only

Comment: Is the backend written by you? If so, Maybe it's the backend's problem.

Comment: No backed is not written by me, but backend is perfect because values is api call works but only its not working in this offline functionality

Comment: @vesper If there was problem in backend side than the data don't even get posted but it works actually

As per my debugging the volley gives me incorrect response after the first call

Comment: The first call works cannot prove that the backend hasn't problem, because you have not yet proved that the backend will return 0 if you upload some bad data or some other conditions make it failed. I trend to consider it's backend's problem, because I don't find any obvious mistake in client code you have shown. And in your description, you think it's volley gives you wrong result(return 1 even though the data have not been saved in backend ), actually, not volley but backend give you the wrong result. So I suggest you to check how backend code handle post request!

Comment: @vesper Backend also gives me the response 0 when i enter a bad data, even tho i had also tested by changing response value at backend to only 0 but then also volley returns zero value

Comment: @vesper According to you if client code is perfect then i will try to make changes with backend team

Comment: Yes, we cannot find out problems clearly in client in a short time, so we can ensure the backend is ok at first.

Comment: @vesper I have backend php file also can you help me that?

Comment: By the way, you check response by `string.contains()` method, why did you do like that? In general, it's more recipient to use `equals()` to check result.

Comment: ok, you can show your php code.

Comment: @vesper  i changed my response code to directly print volley response on toast, and also updated OP with backend code

Comment: So, can you tell me what's the whole response result? Just a 0/1 or "HTTP/1.1 0/1"?

Comment: @vesper I am only getting 1 in toast

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you any more help. I really can not find the reason according to your code.

Comment: @vesper np, do you have any suggestions or different approach for this offline functionality so I can try that otherwise thank you for your help sir

Comment: You can change the code for a test. Firstly, ensure the network is ok, and you can set a button to click to upload different data directly, this way can check your upload function is available. Secondly, change the click action of pre button to save some data to your local db, and set another button clicked to upload data which is obtained from your db. Do these checks to exclude problem one by one.